# Error on initialization constexpr compile time array on ibm i 7.3

Tags: c++, ibm-midrange, constexpr

Due to specific IO process on ibm i there's requirement of using display file fields IO.

As follows we need compile time structures for display file values.

After looking at `constexpr` I've decided to try some cpp + templates solution from [here](https://github.com/Jiwan/meta_crush_saga/blob/a5000de3c77f589ce365b5befb59e98a5c4738fa/constexpr_string.hpp).

The final code for my case looks like this:

MYSRC/MYMOD.CPP

```
#include "MYSRC/MODINCH"

template <int N>
constexpr_string<N> make_constexpr_string(const char(&a)[N]) {
    // Provide a function template to deduce N           ^ right here
return constexpr_string<N>(a);
    //                     ^ Forward the parameter to the class template.
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

---

MYSRC/MODINCH.H

```
#include <algorithm>

   #define __IBMCPP_TR1__ 1
#include <QSYSINC/STD(array)>

 using std::size_t;

template <size_t N> // N is the capacity of my string.
class constexpr_string {
private:
    //std::tr1::array<char, N> data_; // Reserve N chars to store anything.  
    char data_[N];
    std::size_t size_;         // The actual size of the string.
public:
    constexpr constexpr_string(const char(&a)[N]): data_{}, size_(N - 1)
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            data_[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
    constexpr iterator begin() {  return data_;   }       // Points at the beggining of the storage.
    constexpr iterator end() {  return data_ + size_;   } // Points at the end of the stored string.

};
```

The code above compiles with

```
CRTCPPMOD MODULE(QTEMP/MYMOD) SRCFILE(MYLIB/MYSRC) SRCMBR(MYMOD)
OPTIMIZE(40) DBGVIEW(*ALL) LANGLVL(*EXTENDED0X)
```

for both `char data_[N];` and `std::tr1::array<char, N> data_;`

However, when I try to populate instance of `constexpr_string` like this:

```
#include "MYSRC/MODINCH"

template <int N>
constexpr_string<N> make_constexpr_string(const char(&a)[N]) {
    // Provide a function template to deduce N           ^ right here
return constexpr_string<N>(a);
    //                     ^ Forward the parameter to the class template.
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
auto test1 = make_constexpr_string("blabla");
constexpr_string<7> test("blabla");
return 0;
}
```

error instantly fails compilation with this message
`CZP0063(30) The text "constexpr_string" is unexpected.` right at the ctor line. For me this looks like compiler can not determine the `constexpr` keyword in this situation, but why?

Did I messed somewhere in code or this usage just currently unsupported?

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) is the supported features of ibm compiler and the IBM XLC++ supports `constexpr` as far, as I can deduct from given table.

Answer (score 0):

Given this is tagged as `ibm-midrange`, I'm not sure the feature set of IBM XLC++ is the proper reference to use.  I think you want to be using [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzarf/sc094816.pdf?view=kc) instead.  In particular if you want to use C++0x features (which are not yet fully supported), you need to compile using `LANGLVL(*EXTENDED0X)`.

For further information, [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzarg/cpp0x_exts.htm) shows information on support for ILE C++0x language extensions.

Comment: sure, but not compiles with `LANGLVL(*EXTENDED)` or any other

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment here.  Did you try compiling this with `LANGLVL(*EXTENDED0X)`?  Per the link given, generalized constant expressions (`constexpr`) are not supported unless specifically enabled by this compilation flag.

Comment: of course I've tried this option. this stated right in the question defenition of build command used: `CRTCPPMOD MODULE(QTEMP/MYMOD) SRCFILE(MYLIB/MYSRC) SRCMBR(MYMOD)
OPTIMIZE(40) DBGVIEW(*ALL) LANGLVL(*EXTENDED0X)`

Comment: My apologies for my less than helpful answers on this.  I've been on travel and was attempting to help out where I could but I didn't look over the question as well as I normally would have.  Unfortunately, it does seem as though IBM has some work to do on supporting even this standard.  At this point, there's not much to do other than report it to them as deficient.

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify this on the `ibm-midrange` system because I don't have access to the CPP compiler there but I think I've found your issue:

```
#include "MYSRC/MODINCH"
template <int N>
constexpr_string<N> make_constexpr_string;  // <------ You are missing this semicolon
...
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto test1 = make_constexpr_string("blabla");
    constexpr_string<7> test("blabla");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, I meant `main` part was untouched except declaration of `constexpr_string` valriables... so no semicolon missed.
btw, will update my question with full source

Comment: Ah my mistake.  I misunderstood your `...`.  I presumed you were trying to forward declare a template expression (which I'm not actually sure is supported).  The reason MYMOD.CPP compiles and not your true main is that MYMOD.CPP never tries to instantiate an instance of `make_constexpr_string`.  If a template is never used, the compiler doesn't have enough information to do more than the most cursory checks.

Comment: that's the point. it simply implies that the latest ibm i c++ compiler does not aware of `constexpr` inspite of guarantee in ibm docs